# gtag Google Analytics cookie expiration

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I want to change the default expiration time of the Google Analytics cookies.
I've used the below snippet to initialize the page.
However, the cookie_expires value is not taken into account. (the cookie expires 2 years from now instead of 1)

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-xxx"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-xxx', {
      'anonymize_ip': true,
      'cookie_expires': 31536000,  {# 1 Year in seconds #} //TODO not working
      'send_page_view': false    
  });
```

I haven't any Tag Manager workspace.
Any idea?

Comment: have you cleared your current 2 year cookie? As well as is {# 1 Year in seconds #} valid?

Comment: Yes, I've tried. (The doc says that the cookie_expires time is added to the current date on every hit, so also if I do not clear the cookie it should work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem.
I was sending the page hit with `gtag('config', 'GA_TRACKING_ID', {<pageview_parameters>});`
This reset the config previously set.